# JavaScript: scroll position (Webkit engine)

Tags: javascript

I'm currently trying to use JavaScript to find out how far down the page the user has scrolled; for Firefox 8.0, the keyword is *pageYOffset*.

To say things mechanically:

1. The **page** has a certain height. In Firefox, the useful object is *document.documentElement.scrollHeight*.
2. The **browser's visible area** also has a certain height. In Firefox, the object is *window.innerHeight*; in IE8, *document.documentElement.clientHeight*.
3. I need to know where the user is in the page vertically; in other words, **how many pixels down the page** the user has scrolled.

**Does Webkit have a DOM object that refers to the current scroll position?**

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think all you need is:

```
var scrollTop = document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
var scrolLeft = document.body.scrollLeft || document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
```

The first half covers webkit and mozilla, the latter for IE.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, there's the IE problem solved.

Also, it turns out that in the case of Chrome and Safari, as well as IE, the scrollbar is brought back to the top for a split second when the page is reloaded.

The window.onload event which I used for testing was called before the bar was brought back to the right position.

Thank you, I was worried about what I was going to do with IE.

Comment: Hi Julien - welcome to SO. If you are commenting on an answer, it's better to "add comment" to the answer you are talking about (like this). What you have created here is another answer message - and these may not stay in order in the future, and so will lose their meaning (you can delete an answer that you created).

Comment: Sincerest apologies, I only just saw this. Thank you for the advice; I'll be sure to use the "add comment" option in the future. (I've also turned on e-mail notifications so I see these responses next time.)